# How to setup encrypted payment settings in paypal production?

Tags: paypal, production, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I successfully worked through Ryan Bates screencasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security and got Paypal Website Payments Standard working with IPN and encrypted payment settings in the Sandbox.

When I try to setup the encrypted payment settings in my production environment though I find the settings page looks completely different to the settings i was getting in my 'business' account in the sandbox. The 'profile' section has no mention of 'encrypted payment settings'.

1. What is the difference between a business and a personal account in the sandbox? Do i need a 'business' account and what is it?
2. Depending on 1, how do i setup my encrypted payment setttings?
3. I am using an Australian PayPal account, could that have anything to do with it?

btw - I had no problem taking payments and using IPN on my production account without encryption.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Business and test accounts are supposed to mimic the real accounts. For example, when a test user buys your product that money gets added to the business account. 
3) Doubt it. Sandbox is meant for everyone.

**Update**: Looks like the Australian site is different.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the reason for my confusion was that the Australian Pay Pal website is presented differently from the international version - and looks nothing like the Sandbox.

So, for the record, provided your account Type is Business the encryption settings on the Australian version are at:

Profile > My Selling Tools > Encrypted Payment Settings (right at the bottom of the page)

Comment: IPN works fine for me in Sandbox mode, though to use encryption you do have to upload your certificates in both environments and use an environment specific certificate id.